# return value does not match function return type

Tags: c++

I'm getting errors in vs2013 with the dot_product functions.

Here is my usage for `dot_product`

```
// This is in a header file.
Bool circles_collide(const Circle* a, const Circle* b)
{
   const float radiusSum = a->radius + b->radius;
   const Vector2D distance = subtract_vector(&(a->center), &(b->center));
   return dot_product(&distance, &distance) <= radiusSum * radiusSum;
}


 //This is the the implementation of dot_product in another header file.
float dot_product(const Vector2D* a, const Vector2D* b) 
{
    return a->x * b->x + a->y * b->y;
}
```

I'm also getting same errors with other functions that use const parameters. Anyone know what could cause this problem?

Edit:: I took a screenshot of the errors, [link]http://puu.sh/kaoiy/3baebde6af.png

Comment: Can you please add more information on the errors you get?

Comment: What is `Bool` defined as? The standard c++ data type is `bool` (note lower-case 'b').

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as well as the exact error message it causes.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter, yeah you are right, these code were written in C and I'm moving them into C++. Thanks for pointing out this very stupid mistake :P it fixed most of my errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dot_product(&distance, &distance) <= radiusSum * radiusSum;` will result in a c++ `bool` type.

`Bool circles_collide(const Circle* a, const Circle* b)` expects to return `Bool`.

I don't know what `Bool` is, but looks like the compiler can't make implicitly make one from `bool`.